# Does Agent Smith only see coding?

Tags: the-matrix, agent-smith

In the Matrix Revolutions when Agent Smith turns the Oracle into another Smith it shows the coding and the change Smith is doing around him and the other Smiths

Is this the way Smith sees the Matrix or would he see it the way any human would see it?

Comment: We don't know. We know that green squigly things are raw matrix code, but that is also just a different level of abstraction or interpretation, if you will. In reality, Matrix is radio signal and bytes and bits. Humans have "jack", a piece of technology that translates/interprets signal from the Matrix into the things human brain can understand. And things here means electrical and chemical signals. Whether programs have something similar, some form of interpreter, we don't know. Maybe by looking into Sati... We know programs could be made to interact with Matrix and look human.

Comment: Well, Smith was complaining about stench, so I guess his senses were normal, at least in first film.

Comment: @Mithoron he could have been lying and that could have been part of his interrogation technique programming.

Comment: @jo1storm Except it was neither... He was going for honesty this time.  Would you say taking off the contact microphone, that he had to actually listen to, to have contact with other Agents, was also normal? While they had unusual abilities and perhaps could see the code like Neo, they were using bodies that were human, at least originally.

Comment: Doesn't really matter. The original body is in a pod somewhere. The virtual simulacrum of a body is hijacked by a sentient program. The question is how that sentient program perceives virtual reality of the Matrix. And the answer is: we don't know. Even those green squigly falling symbols that Cypher mentioned and operators and we as the audience see on some screens are a simulation for the purpose of human eyes when they need to do some coding. You might as well ask how an octopus perceives sea as compared to human.